# Javascript iterator in return statement

Tags: javascript, iterator

I've been studying javascript examples and I came across this:

```
var numb=1;

function funName(numb){
    // function work
    return numb+1;
}
```

In this example I'm not sure how the number is iterating each time on return numb+1; I thought it would have to look more like numb=numb+1;

Does this just work cause the '+1' is in the return statement?

Comment: This function just adds `+1` to whatever is passed to it.

Comment: you can use that in loops by assigning the return value of the function call to a local variable before or in between iterations of your loop. For example: `for (var numb = 1; numb < 5; numb = funName(numb)) { // do something with numb 1, 2, 3, 4 }` or `var numb = 0; while((numb = funName(numb)) < 5) { // do something with numb 1, 2, 3, 4 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code never touches the `numb` variable you define on line 1 after that line.

The function has a locally scoped variable, also called `numb`, declared in the arguments list which masks it.

None of the code you've provided modifies any variable. The function (which you don't call in your example) just returns a value that has 1 added to the value that was passed to it.

Comment: So would I have to call something like numb=funName(numb); for this to actually iterate the variable(in line 1)?

Comment: Yes. But forgetting the function and just having `numb++` would be simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the non snarky answer